# How to make unicode characters visible in Emacs?

Tags: fonts, emacs, unicode, gentoo

When I open a file with some UTF-8 text in it the characters show up as boxes.

I think I have a font missing, because I can safely edit these boxes and the changes will turn out correctly when I look at them in another text editor (for example from Vim in terminal).

Also at startup Emacs prints out the following warning:

```
Warning: no fonts matching `-*-fixed-medium-r-normal-*-16-*-*-*-*-*-iso8859-1' available [2 times]
```

I have tried installing several X.org font packages to my system but that doesn't seem to help.

Using GNU Emacs 22.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try and set DejaVu Sans Mono as the font. That's a font for Unicode that is normally installed by default on any Linux distribution.

Comment: This kind of solved my problem, as to use DejaVu Sans Mono font I had to upgrade to Emacs 23, as 22 doesn't support TrueType fonts. Apparently after upgrade Emacs automagically selected DejaVu Sans Mono as its default font.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: Emacs 23 added xft support which makes life much more livable in the world of fonts and emacs.

Answer (score 3):

The fonts error is probably a red herring. This message usually comes up because Emacs thinks it should use a font this specification for some of its output. If you need/want to fix it then finding the faulty specification and fixing it is the recommended route (e.g. http://braeburn.aquamacs.org/code/master/etc/PROBLEMS).

Comment: Upgrading to Emacs 23 also seemed to remove this warning message.

Answer (score 1):

Unicode (name or hex):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145889/emacs-xterm-mousepad-c-unicode-and-utf-8-trying-to-make-sense-of-it-all

Comment: What do you mean by "name or hex"?

And what should I look for in that question you pointed out?

Comment: There are some answer for this problem ..

Comment: If you mean (prefer-coding-system 'utf-8) then I do have that in my .emacs file. I also tried adding all the following lines, but that didn't help.